# NSNotificationCenter get notifications on NSMutableDictionary addObject

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotificationcenter

How can I get notifications with NSNotificationCenter when object is added to NSMutableDictionary?

Also are there any notifications for immutable NSDictionary?

Comment: **of course not.** but you can write an own inherited class from `NSDictionary` and you can override the relevant methods and it can post the extra notification for you at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the beauty of inheritance :)

```
#define kSomeDictionarySetAValue @"SomeDictionarySetAValue"

@interface SomeDictionary : NSMutableDictionary

@end

@implementation SomeDictionary

- (void) setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    [super setValue:value forKey:key];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kSomeDictionarySetAValue
                                                        object:self];
}

@end
```